# Matrices inversion proof: $A(I-A)^{-1}=(I-A)^{-1} A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A$ be a square matrix such that $I-A$ is non-singular, prove that
>
> $$A(I-A)^{-1}=(I-A)^{-1} A$$

I can prove that $A(I-A)=(I-A)A$.

But I don't know where to go next.

Comment: Hint: $A = I - (I- A)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $I - A$ is non-singular, we know $(I - A)^{-1}$ exists. So...

$$A(I-A) = (I-A)A$$
$$(I - A)^{-1}{\bf A (I -A)}(I - A)^{-1} = (I - A)^{-1} {\bf (I - A)A}(I - A)^{-1}$$

$$(I - A)^{-1} A \cdot I = I \cdot A(I - A)^{-1}$$
$$(I - A)^{-1} A = A (I - A)^{-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

Starting from $A(I-A) = (I-A)A$, multiply both sides by $(I-A)^{-1}$ on the left and also on the right.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $(I-A)A(I-A)^{-1}=A(I-A)(I-A)^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

You know (directly from the definition of the inverse matrix) that $(I-A)(I-A)^{-1}=(I-A)^{-1}(I-A)$. From this you get
\begin{gather*}
(I-A)(I-A)^{-1}=(I-A)^{-1}(I-A)\\
(I-A)^{-1}-A(I-A)^{-1}=(I-A)^{-1}-(I-A)^{-1}A\\
-A(I-A)^{-1}=-(I-A)^{-1}A\\
A(I-A)^{-1}=(I-A)^{-1}A
\end{gather*}